# Using Datetimepicker using javascript alert message showing up blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using the bootstrap datetimepicker and trying to save the date
when the alert on the page pops up it is showing up as blank.
Please help, if more information is needed please let me know.
Both lines of code are on the same html.erb page

This is the script that I am using to set the date

```
<div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
  <!--Trying to figure out how to capture the data -->
  <input type='text' data-date-format="MM/DD/YYYY" class="form-control" />
  <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
```

script I am trying to use to store the data

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#datetimepicker1').on('change', function() {
    alert($('#datetimepicker1').val());
  });
</script>
```

initialize datetimepicker

```
   $(".datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
   endDate: new Date,
   format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
   autoclose: true,
    minViewMode: 1,
  todayBtn: "linked"
   });
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" id="Date1">
         $(function () {
             var value = $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker("getDate");
              });
          </script> This is what I am using to capture the data

Comment: how do you initialize datetimepicker ?

Comment: $(".datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
  endDate: new Date,
  format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
  autoclose: true,
  minViewMode: 1,
  todayBtn: "linked"
});

Comment: you're trying to alert the date value on change ?

Comment: I want to store the data in javascript so that I can move it to a database is my final goal  isn't this jsfiddle pulling the data into a string?http://jsfiddle.net/HFuDg/313/

Comment: how do you want to save it to a database? via Ajax or form submit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From whatever I could understand, you probably are looking for this!

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$('#myDate').datepicker({  format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});

$('#myDate').on('change', function() {
   var x = $('#myDate').val();
   //alert("value of date is "+ x);
  //do some ajax call and put/post the date like, 
        $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: 'http://yourUrl',
                data: {"date": x}, //in case String is to be sent!
                success: function(x) {
                //do some stuff on success, you can go with callback implementation too
                 console.log(x);
                },
                error: function(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }
       })
});
});
```

Comment: Okay, so pretty much I need to capture this information through Ajax and then I can use some other stuff to get it into my database? With javascript it would capture the data when the form submitted? Thank you for all your help.